# Grab the part after '\' using a regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a problem that I think lends itself to using regular expressions, however I am not sure of how all the syntax works for my particular case. I have a string which will always be in the form of `Company\user` I would simply like to grab the string after the `\`  However I don't want to include the `\`

My attempt was this:

```
var user = Regex.Match(userName,@"\*").ToString();
```

But this only yielded the empty string. How to achieve this?

Comment: Do you really need regex? What's with `userName.Substring(userName.IndexOf('\\')+1)`

Comment: Agreed - I'd use IndexOf. But if you really want to use regex: `var user = Regex.Match(userName, @".*\\(.*)").Groups[1].ToString();`

Comment: @MatthewWatson The regular expression `\\(.*)` would suffice. There is no need for the initial `.*`. Then it needs to go into a string, so `"\\\\(.*)"`.

Comment: @AdrianHHH True. Or `@"\\(.*)"` if using `@`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make use of the Substring method you can accomplish this easily (and in a more readable fashion).

As the comments suggest the following would serve your purpose:

```
userName.Substring(userName.IndexOf('\\')+1)
```

Here is some more information on substring from MSDN: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

To solve it in Regex:

```
var user = Regex.Match(userName, @"(?<=\\).*").ToString();
```

The `(?<=\\)` is a lookbehind that matches the `\` part of the string but does not capture it in the final match.

However I agree that @MatthewWatson's answer using Split is ideal if you don't require a regex solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just to provide a third way of doing this (error handling omitted for brevity!):

```
var user = userName.Split('\\')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var m = Regex.Match(@"Company\User", @"[^\\]+\\(.+)");
if (m.Groups.Count > 1)
{
    var user = m.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would parse it in this way:

```
var text = "Company\\Luke Skywalker";

var regex = new Regex(
      "^Company\\\\(?<user>.*?)$",
      RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline
    );

var matches = regex.Match(text);

if (matches.Success) {
    var user = matches.Groups["user"].Value;
    // "Luke Skywalker"
}
```